# Public Class no known class method?

Tags: objective-c

Hi I want that this code is a public class:

```
+ (void) alcSubstract {
    NSLog(@"tes");
    if (alkOld == 0) {

    } else {
        Promille = 0;
        alkOld = alkOld - (0.1/3600);
        [self calculation];
    }
}
```

but now there is an error at `[self calculation]`
Error: No known class Method for selector calc...

Calculation looks like this:

```
- (void)calculation
{
    NSLog(@"Starting calcultion");
    if (Mann == true) {
        Promille = alkGramm/(0.7*gewicht);
    } else {
        Promille = alkGramm/(0.6*gewicht);
    }
    //NSLog(@"%f", Promille);
    promilleOut.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    if (Promille >= 1) {
        promilleOut.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    } else if (Promille >= 1.5){
        promilleOut.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    promilleOut.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", alkOld + Promille];
    alkOld = [promilleOut.text floatValue];
    [self timeCalc];
    alkGramm = 0;

}
```

`

Comment: You are declaring alcSubstract as a class method, hence the error. Try changing it to - (void)alcSubtract

Comment: Public Class? do you mean Class Method?

Comment: I'd recommend getting used to Objective-C naming conventions, which make mixing German and English difficult. Properties should start with lowercase, and instance variables should start with an underscore. Like property "promille" and instance variable "_promille".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a instance method from class method like that. When you refer self from a class method, then it'll look for another class method of given name.

**Solution 1:**

Change `calculation` to class method

```
+ (void)calculation
```

**Solution 2**

Create instance of the particular class and use it:

```
+ (void) alcSubstract
{
    NSLog(@"tes");
    if (alkOld == 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        Promille = 0;
        alkOld = alkOld - (0.1/3600);
        YourClass *obj = [[YourClass alloc] init]; // Example only, make the object a global or static one
        [obj calculation];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think he can make calculation a class method, it refers to instance variables and other instance methods (I think, not enough code to be sure)

Comment: yes your right I cant't make calculation to a class method

Answer (score 0):

`- (void)calculation` declares calculation to be an instance method (the '-' specifies an instance method)

`+(void)alcSubtract` declares alcSubtract to be a class method (the '+' specifies a class method.

Within the class method `alcSubtract`, self refers to an instance of the class Class specific to whatever class you're defining.  `[self calculation]` attempts to invoke a method on that class (class method).  But, since `calculation` is an instance method, and not a class method, you get a compiler error.

From looking at the code in `calculation` my guess is that `alcSubtract` should be an instance method.  Alternatively, several methods that are currently instance methods should be changed to be class methods.